# How do I convert an int to hexadecimal and then put it as a string format?

Tags: c, string, hex

For example, let's say I have the decimal number 10.

I want to be able to go form an integer of 10 to a string of "0a".

How do I do that?

Note: I don't want anything printed out.

Comment: With `sprintf`. Look it up.

Comment: Your title is very poorly stated, and may be exposing a basic misunderstanding. You see, int and "hexidecimal" are not the same class of notion. The former is a c language concept (a type for representing a subset of the integers), while the latter (like decimal, octal and binary) is a base in which number can be represented in written form and is not a language concept. What you seem to be trying to ask is how has to obtain a string containing the hexadecimal representation of an int.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sprintf to represent a numeric value in hexadecimal format:

```
sprintf(buff, "%0.2x\n", 10)
```

Take also a look at [dmckee's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513197/how-do-i-convert-an-int-to-hexadecimal-and-then-put-it-as-a-string-format/21513222#comment32479868_21513197) on int/hexadecimal misunderstanding.